# Ignite Select query on Cache load time

Tags: c++, cassandra, ignite

I am developing an Ignite c++ application. When I try to update cache from Cassandra table using `loadcache()` function its load the entire table. 
 I want to execute a select query during the load time. In Java, we can do this just like `loadcache (query)`. Is there any similar function available on c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently there is only `LoadCache` without parameters available.

Comment: Is there any other method to achieve this?

Comment: To my knowledge, currently there is not way to pass parameters when loading from C++. This will be added in the future. I would suggest to create a very simple Java program that will start a client node and only call `loadCache` method. There you will be able to provide arguments.

Comment: Ok. Let me try.